# Let $U$ be a normal operator. Prove, that there exists a sequence $\{ U_n \}$ which converges to $U$ uniformly.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

I was told to use the "uniform limit theorem" here, but this theorem is just true for functions, and not operators?

What I am actually doing is to prove that $f(U)$ is normal if $f$ is a function from the disk algebra.

So what I did here was to use the spectral theorem:

$$f(U) = \int_{\sigma(U)} f(z) dE(z)$$

where $dE(z)$ is the spectral measure for $U$.

And if $f(U)$ is continuous i.e. there exists such a $\{ f_n \}$ and $\{ U_n \}$ that $f_n (U_n) \rightarrow f(U)$ uniformly, then $f(U)$ will also be a normal operator.

I already found my sequence $\{ f_n \}$ for disk algebra functions, but I am having trouble finding a sequence $\{ U_n \}$

Any ideas?

Comment: Isn't $f(U)$ always normal (whether or not $U$ is)? Since $f(U)^* = \overline f (U)$ so that $f(U)f(U)^* = f(U) \overline f (U) = (f \overline f) (U) = f(U)^* f(U)$

Comment: @EvangelopoulosPhoevos How can I prove that $f(U)^* = \overline{f}(U)$? For which kind of $f$ is this true?

Comment: @EvangelopoulosPhoevos My Professor told me that the fact that $f(U)$ is normal comes from the fact that $U$ is normal, and I should use the spectral theorem to prove it. Here, $f$ is from the disk algebra, and we've shown that there exists a sequence $\{ f_n \}$ which is uniformly convergent to $f$. So because $f_n (U) \rightarrow f (U)$, this would prove that $f$ is continuous and thus preserving the normality of $f(U)$. What I'm asking is if what we need to prove is actually the uniform convergence of $f_n (U_n)$, so that $U_n \rightarrow U$, and not "just" $f_n (U) \rightarrow f(U)$?

Comment: It is true for every bounded measurable $f \colon \sigma (U) \to \mathbb C$. It is one of the basic properties of the functional caclulus. Here is a proof: Since for every $S \subset \sigma(U)$, $E(S)$ is a projection (and thus self-adjoint) , you have that $\overline{E_{x,y}} = E_{y,x}$ for every $x,y \in H$. This is because 
$$\overline{ E_{x,y}(S)} = \overline {(E(S)x,y)}= (y, E(S)x) = (E(S)y ,x) =  E_{y,x}(S).$$
Hence, 
$$(\bar{f}(U)x,y)= \int_K \bar f  d E_{x,y} = \overline{ \int_K f d  E_{y,x}} = \overline{(f(U)y,x)}=(x,f(U)y) $$
so that $f(U)^* = \bar f(U)$.

Comment: @EvangelopoulosPhoevos Thanks. But what if I take an arbitrary polynomial $p$ instead (so its domain is not restricted to $\sigma(U)$)? Nagy's book tells us to use the "spectral representation of unitary operators", but I don't see how (let $U$ be unitary here)